# What are the bosses and when do they appear?

Tags: imbroglio

There are multiple references to "bosses" in the developer's design notes.

> I started with the enemy spawns divided into fairly explicit "waves", like maybe four would come at once then a break, then two at a time with shorter breaks between, then one boss, that kind of thing.

https://mightyvision.blogspot.com/2016/06/imbroglio-notes-3-monsters.html

> The 16/16 endboss worked pretty well

> It seemed good to get some kind of reward for killing a boss

> Both bosses had this effect for a while

https://mightyvision.blogspot.com/2016/11/imbroglio-notes-11-spoiler-warning.html

What are these bosses and when do they appear? Do they have a small % chance to appear at any time or are they triggered by a gem level?

For that matter, is the Minotaur a boss or a mid/mini-boss? I think I saw one appear at like 55 gems, which doesn't seem to line up with the developer's goal of making things happen at multiples of 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be two fairly rare bosses monsters.

> Dragons and unicorns are powerful monsters that come out after a ton of turns.

https://vivafringe.wordpress.com/2017/07/20/lets-spoil-868-hacks-secret-level-and-talk-about-good-secrets-vs-bad-secrets/amp/

[image: dragon]

[image: unicorn]